# how to derive the formula of average DC voltage of half and full wave rectifier?

Tags: formula

i need the derivations that how these formulae comes

```
Vavg=Vpeak/pi for half wave rectifier
Vavg=2Vpeak/pi for full wave
```

Comment: Better off at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better off at [chiphacker.com](http://chiphacker.com/) or (once it goes public) the new [Electronics and Robotics stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651/electronics-and-robotics) if you want to know the electronics side of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full wave is double of half wave because both 'bumps' are used. That is easy.

Now derive the halfwave:

```
V(t) = Vpeak*sin(t);
```

2 PI is a full circle and we only use half of that : 0->PI

```
Vavg = Vpeak*integral(sin(t),0 -> PI)/2*PI
```

indefinite integral of sin(x) = -cos(x)

```
 = Vpeak*(-cos(PI) + cos(0))/2*PI 
 = Vpeak*(-(-1) +  1) / 2*PI
 = Vpeak ( 1 + 1) / 2*PI
 = Vpeak / PI
```

that's it.

Comment: oh thanks a lot. just 1 thing is not clear as my physics is not so good. how we know that we should multiply Vpeak to sin(t) to get the voltage???

Comment: Because that is the definition of Vpeak : it is the amplitude of the sine wave. A sine wave goes from 0 to 1 to -1 to 0 again. So the peak voltage occurs at 1 and -1 points. To scale to the real voltage you multiply by Vpeak. (for more details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current)

Comment: @Sweety Khan A rectifier takes as input a wave and outputs a DC voltage.

Comment: thank u soo much Peter and James for helping me instead of abstaining my question like others . thanx a lot. my best wishes r for u